# How can I count unique comma-separated names in multiple cells

Tags: worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2010

I am new to VBA I want to count unique names separated by comma & space in the range I got UDF from the same website but it is looking into only one cell.

```
Function ListCount(list As String, delimiter As String) As Long
Dim arr As Variant
arr = Split(list, delimiter)
ListCount = UBound(arr) - LBound(arr) + 1
End Function

Function RemoveDuplicates(list As String, delimiter As String) As String
Dim arrSplit As Variant, i As Long, tmpDict As New Dictionary, tmpOutput As String
arrSplit = Split(list, delimiter)
For i = LBound(arrSplit) To UBound(arrSplit)
    If Not tmpDict.Exists(arrSplit(i)) Then
        tmpDict.Add arrSplit(i), arrSplit(i)
        tmpOutput = tmpOutput & arrSplit(i) & delimiter
    End If
Next i
If tmpOutput <> "" Then tmpOutput = Left(tmpOutput, Len(tmpOutput) - Len(delimiter))
RemoveDuplicates = tmpOutput
'housekeeping
Set tmpDict = New Dictionary
End Function
```

can some one modify for range of cells.
thanks
rao

Answer (score 3):

This formula will also replace all the vba:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(ISERROR(FIND(TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(TEXTJOIN(",",TRUE,A:A),",",REPT(" ",999)),(ROW(1:100)-1)*999+1,999)),MID(SUBSTITUTE(TEXTJOIN(",",TRUE,A:A),",",REPT(" ",999)),1,(ROW(1:100)-1)*999)))))
```

[image]

---

TEXTJOIN was introduced in Office 365 Excel.  If you do not have it, use this code that mimics the function:

```
Function TEXTJOIN(delim As String, skipblank As Boolean, arr)
    Dim d As Long
    Dim c As Long
    Dim arr2()
    Dim t As Long, y As Long
    t = -1
    y = -1
    If TypeName(arr) = "Range" Then
        arr2 = arr.Value
    Else
        arr2 = arr
    End If
    On Error Resume Next
    t = UBound(arr2, 2)
    y = UBound(arr2, 1)
    On Error GoTo 0

    If t >= 0 And y >= 0 Then
        For c = LBound(arr2, 1) To UBound(arr2, 1)
            For d = LBound(arr2, 1) To UBound(arr2, 2)
                If arr2(c, d) <> "" Or Not skipblank Then
                    TEXTJOIN = TEXTJOIN & arr2(c, d) & delim
                End If
            Next d
        Next c
    Else
        For c = LBound(arr2) To UBound(arr2)
            If arr2(c) <> "" Or Not skipblank Then
                TEXTJOIN = TEXTJOIN & arr2(c) & delim
            End If
        Next c
    End If
    TEXTJOIN = Left(TEXTJOIN, Len(TEXTJOIN) - Len(delim))
End Function
```

Answer (score 1):

For a **single cell**, use:

```
=listcount(removeduplicates(A1,","),",")
```

[image]

For **multiple cells** use:

```
=listcount(removeduplicates(TEXTJOIN(",",TRUE,A1:A2),","),",")
```

[image]

If your version of Excel does not support `TEXTJOIN()`, then code your own.