# Count number of unique comma separated values in an entire column

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, microsoft-excel-2016

In Excel 2016, I have a column with cells that contain comma delimited strings. I am trying to count the number of unique strings in the entire column.

I know how to count the number of unique comma delimited strings within one cell and I know that I could collapse the data in my column into a single cell and do it that way. The problem is that would exceed the character limit of one cell since I have too much data.

Here is an example image which shows what I am trying to do:

[image: example image]

The number 8 in B3 is the final result I am looking to get.

I don't know if this is possible to do using an array formula but I have attempted to write down the logic of a vba function to accomplish this. What I have so far is this pseudocode:

```
Function UniqueK (cells As Range) As Integer
    Dim count As Integer
    Dim temp_array() As String
    Dim final_array() As String
    Dim cell As Variant

For cell In cells
    temp_array = split(cell,",")
    append temp_array to final_array
Next cell

remove duplicates in final_array
count = number of entries in final_array
UniqueK = count
End function
```

This is probably a really slow way of doing it and I was wondering if there was an easier way of accomplishing this task or if there is an existing way of doing it that I could not find. If not, are there ways to remove duplicates in a string array and ways to append a string array to the end of another string array so I can get this function to work?

Comment: see: https://superuser.com/questions/1255077/how-can-i-count-unique-comma-separated-names-in-multiple-cells/1255139#1255139

Comment: This answer will not work because my column has too much data to fit into one cell using textjoin

Comment: Then use the vba code from the other linked answer.

Comment: Umm, can you explain why [my VBA answer](//superuser.com/a/1332369) to the duplicate target question, [How can I count unique selections from multiple selections in a drop down list (Excel)](//superuser.com/q/1332285), is not suitable? All you need to do is install the UDF and enter this formula anywhere in your worksheet: `=CountDistintMultiSelections(A:A)-1`.

Comment: It is suitable, you're right. That function didn't do exactly what I was trying to do but I was able to use it after I used text to columns on my data and fed that entire range to the function. Thank you!